# Rename database object during restore

Tags: sql-server, restore

Is there a way to rename database objects such as tables, stored-procedures, etc, during a restore of a .BAK file to a new database?

Comment: As in during the restore process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to do this after the restoration process, when the database is in `NORECOVERY` mode.  Concurrently?  No, there isn't a way.

Comment: I will just rename the objects once the restore is done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No you can not change an object name (other than the actual database) when you restore the database.  You'll have to wait for the database to be restored and brought online (WITH RECOVERY) before you can change object names.  If the object was renamed in the source database and you are rolling the logs forward the object will automatically be renamed as the logs are rolled forward.